Transferring files from remote host to two hard-drives, one fast one slow? (sync fast to slow)
I have terabytes of data on a remote host that I'm transferring.
Currently I'm using rsync -az. Recently I purchased a large external hard-drive [USB-C, Toshiba]; but it seems slower than my internal SSD.
During the transfer, how do I setup a multiphase copy, from remote-host to internal SSD to external SSD, such that only files that exist on neither internal SSD nor external SSD are transferred from remote-host?
FWIW: Not limited to rsync, remote-host is Linux x86_64 and local host is an Apple Macbook Pro with M3 Pro running macOS 15.2.

Let me restate your problem to ensure that I am doing what you want:

You want to transfer all files from the remote machine to your internal SSD, unless the files are already present and up to date on the external drive.

To do this, you need to do two steps:

Figure out which files are identical between the remote server and your external drive.
Do an rsync from the remote drive to your internal drive, excluding the list of files from step #1.

Assuming you have a file from step #1, the second step is easy you just need to provide the file to your rsync command with the option: --exclude-from=file.txt
To generate the file (of identical files) you are going to have to do some work. If you rsync -n remote:/some/path /external it will generate "dry run" output (of which files the command would sync), then you need to find all the files on the remote server and difference the two lists to get list of files that are identical.
You might need some additional switches for the dry run rsync, I would consider:

-r - recursive
-c - to force checksums
-v - verbose

